# Build compile time sql query string based on parameters

Tags: c++

I joined a project recently and in the codebase I noticed a piece of code for building sql query dynamically, based on some predefined column names.
The thing is that it is pretty inefficient, because the query is always the same, and it is built every time the system asks database for data. The code, simplified, looks more or less like this:

```
string prepSelectDynamic() 
{
    const char* column1 = "col1";
    const char* column2 = "col2";
    const char* column3 = "col3";
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "SELECT ";
    ss << column1 << ", ";
    ss << column2 << ", ";
    ss << column3 << ", ";
    return ss.str();
}
```

Needless to say there are more than 25 such columns and as we can expect building such query is pretty inefficient every time.

The column name variables are of course defined in other place and are used in some other places so we don't want to write everything in one giant string. But that is actually something I would like to get here. Why build this query dynamically every time the system queries DB (every couple of seconds)? Wouldn't it be nicer to construct this query dynamically but at compile time?

What I would like to achieve is a different method, based on variadic templates or auto which would accept the column names as arguments and would construct the string, but at compile time. I would like to use it like this:

```
auto query = prepSelectStatic(column1, column2, column3);
```

I would like this to essentially be an equivalent to:

```
string prepSelectStatic()
{
    return "SELECT col1, col2, col3"s;
}
```

I started playing with the template I would like to have. I would like my function to look something like this:

```
template<class... T>
string buildQueryCompileTime(T... cols)
{  
    string res("select ");
    std::apply([&](auto... args) { ((res += cols + ", "), ...); }, std::move(cols)...);
    return res;
}
```

This compiles fine but when I try to use it like that (below) I get some strange errors:

```
    auto res = buildQueryCompileTime(column1, column2, column3);
```

Could you please help me finish this?

The errors are:

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'std::string buildQueryCompileTime(T ...) [with T = {const char*, const char*, const char*}; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]':
prog.cc:27:37:   required from here
prog.cc:10:50: error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [3]' to binary 'operator+'
   10 |     std::apply([&](auto... args) { ((res += cols + ", "), ...); }, std::move(cols)...);
      |                                             ~~~~~^~~~~~
prog.cc:10:15: error: no matching function for call to 'apply(buildQueryCompileTime<const char*, const char*, const char*>(const char*, const char*, const char*)::<lambda(auto:11 ...)>, std::remove_reference<const char*&>::type, std::remove_reference<const char*&>::type, std::remove_reference<const char*&>::type)'
   10 |     std::apply([&](auto... args) { ((res += cols + ", "), ...); }, std::move(cols)...);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from prog.cc:3:
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/12.0.0/tuple:1856:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Fn, class _Tuple> constexpr decltype(auto) std::apply(_Fn&&, _Tuple&&)'
 1856 |     apply(_Fn&& __f, _Tuple&& __t)
      |     ^~~~~
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/12.0.0/tuple:1856:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:10:15: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 4 provided
   10 |     std::apply([&](auto... args) { ((res += cols + ", "), ...); }, std::move(cols)...);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: "The thing is that it is pretty inefficient" First think about that on the other side (the sql server )the string will be parsed and all values will be converted to native types and so on. Do you believe you can boost up your total application speed if you can faster format strings but the other side is still boring slow? Think first about using a database which can act on native values and has direct operator objects on the interface. If you work string based, forget about speed!

Comment: Yes, good point. Thank you. But anyway I would like to finish this, just to be proficcient in these new C++17 features and just to be able to write such code easily.

Comment: `cols + ", "` This only works if at least one of the operands is a std::string.

Comment: I thought about it, but this doesn't solve the problem. When I change parameters to strings this still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide you two fully different versions of compile time strings and concat operators. Take a look on the examples please. I am in hope it helps...

```
template < class T, T... Chrs>
struct mystring
{
    static auto c_str()
    {
        static char str[] = {Chrs..., 0};
        return str;
    }

    template < T... in>
        constexpr auto operator+( mystring<T,in...>  ) const
        {
            return mystring< T, Chrs..., in...>{};
        }
};




template <class T, T... Chrs>
constexpr auto operator""_s()
{
    return mystring<T, Chrs...>{};
}

// ###############

// Array will contain '\0' at the end and size is accordingly "abcd" -> Size 5

template < size_t Size >
struct mystring2
{
    static constexpr size_t SIZE = Size; 

    static constexpr size_t GetSize() { return Size; }

    constexpr mystring2(const char (&str) [Size])
        : mystring2(str, std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, Size-1>{})
        {}

    template < size_t I, size_t ... Is >
        constexpr mystring2( const char (&str) [I], std::integer_sequence<size_t, Is...>):
            arr{str[Is]..., '\0'}
    {}

    template < size_t I1, size_t ... Is1, size_t I2, size_t ... Is2 >
        constexpr mystring2( const char (&str1) [I1], std::integer_sequence<size_t, Is1...>, const char (&str2) [I2], std::integer_sequence<size_t, Is2...>):
            arr{str1[Is1]..., str2[Is2]..., '\0'}
    {}

    const char arr[Size];

    template < size_t Size1, size_t Size2 >
         static constexpr auto concat( const char (&str1) [Size1], const char (&str2) [Size2] )
         {
             return mystring2< (Size1-1)+Size2 >(str1, std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, Size1-1>{}, str2, std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, Size2-1>{} );
         }

    template < size_t Size2 >
        constexpr auto operator+( mystring2< Size2 > s2 ) const
        {
            return concat( arr, s2.arr );
        }

    constexpr auto c_str() const
    {
        return arr;
    }
};

    template < size_t Size >
constexpr auto to_string(char const (&cstr) [Size])
{
    return mystring2<Size>(cstr);
}

// ###############

// your demo starts here...
constexpr auto col1 = "col1"_s;
constexpr auto col2 = "col2"_s;
constexpr auto col3 = "col3"_s;

template<auto FIRST, auto ... REST>
constexpr auto buildQueryCompileTimeImpl()
{
    if constexpr ( !sizeof...(REST)) return FIRST;
    else return FIRST+","_s+buildQueryCompileTimeImpl< REST...>();
}

template<auto ... T>
constexpr auto buildQueryCompileTime()
{
    return "Select "_s + buildQueryCompileTimeImpl< T...>();
}

// ####

constexpr auto col1_ = to_string("col1");
constexpr auto col2_ = to_string("col2");
constexpr auto col3_ = to_string("col3");

template<auto FIRST, auto ... REST>
constexpr auto buildQueryCompileTimeImpl2()
{
    if constexpr ( !sizeof...(REST)) return FIRST;
    else return FIRST+to_string(",")+buildQueryCompileTimeImpl2< REST...>();
}

template<auto ... T>
constexpr auto buildQueryCompileTime2()
{
    return to_string("Select2 ") + buildQueryCompileTimeImpl2< T...>();
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto x = "That "_s+"is "_s + " my "_s + " string!"_s;
    std::cout << x.c_str() << std::endl;

    constexpr auto y = to_string("Good ") + to_string("Afternoon ")+ to_string("Have fun!");
    std::cout << y.c_str() << std::endl;

    constexpr auto sel = buildQueryCompileTime< col1, col2, col3 >();
    std::cout << sel.c_str() << std::endl;

    constexpr auto sel_ = buildQueryCompileTime2< col1_, col2_, col3_ >();
    std::cout << sel_.c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

OK, it must be said that user defined literals for strings is a non ISO extension but works for gcc and clang. But the other solution works quite well without any extension.

Update: For C++20 there is a user defined string literal solution which is much easier to understand and looks very natural...

```
template<size_t N>
struct string3
{
    std::array<char, N> arr_;

    constexpr string3(const char(&in)[N]) : arr_{}   
    {   
        std::copy(in, in + N, arr_.begin());
    }   

    template < size_t S1, size_t S2 >
    constexpr string3(const std::array<char, S1> s1, const std::array<char,S2> s2) : arr_{}
    {   
        std::copy(s1.begin(), s1.end()-1, arr_.begin());
        std::copy(s2.begin(), s2.end(), arr_.begin()+S1-1);
    }   

    template < size_t S>
    constexpr auto operator+( const string3<S> s2 ) const
    {   
        return string3< N+s2.arr_.size()-1 >(arr_, s2.arr_); 
    }   

    constexpr auto c_str() const
    {   
        return arr_.data();
    }   


};

template < string3 t > constexpr auto operator ""_y() { return t; }

constexpr auto s3_col1 = "col1"_y;
constexpr auto s3_col2 = "col2"_y;
constexpr auto s3_col3 = "col3"_y;

    template<auto FIRST, auto ... REST>
constexpr auto buildQueryCompileTimeImpl3()
{
    if constexpr ( !sizeof...(REST)) return FIRST;
    else return FIRST+","_y+buildQueryCompileTimeImpl3< REST...>();
}

    template<auto ... T>
constexpr auto buildQueryCompileTime3()
{
    return "Select3 "_y + buildQueryCompileTimeImpl3< T...>();
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto sel3 = buildQueryCompileTime3< s3_col1, s3_col2, s3_col3>();
    std::cout << sel3.c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Wow. That is impressive. I was able to understand quickly solution 1, but solution 2 is overly complex for me (I will get back to it tomorrow). But it is something I needed. Thank you. I learnt a lot thanks to this. :-)

Comment: @YotKay: Thanks for your praise :-) Indeed, the second version is a lot more complex but did not need any non ISO extensions. I found another way to do it with the new introduced C++20 user defined string literals. Take a look :-) BTW: If you want to say thanks, use the upvote button :-)